# Unable to create Kubernetes cluster in Google Container Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We are unable to create Kubernetes clusters in our Google Cloud project.  It was working a few weeks ago.  We keep getting the following error:

`Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.zones.get' permission for 'projects/<project code>/zones/us-central1-a'`

However, the role assigned to the user trying to create the cluster is `Project/Owner`, and the service account selected when creating the cluster has `Project/Editor`, which includes the `compute.zones.get` permission.  Even if I give the service account `Project/Owner` it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I inspected your concern and you lack the cloudservices [service account](https://cloud.google.com//compute/docs/access/service-accounts#google_apis_service_account) in IAM. I found that you also opened a thread in the Stackoverflow community for this concern. A current workaround for this issue is to re-enable the Google Cloud Compute Engine API.